# Doctrine multiple discriminator inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine, mapping

I am currently implementing a User system in a simple Symfony framework. I'm using a vendor bundle which includes a basic User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class User
{
    protected $id;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
}
```

This entity of course has some basic properties such as id, username and password. To expand on this, I've created a base user for my own bundle:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class MyBaseUser extends User
{
    protected $address;
    protected $phoneNumber;
}
```

This of course has some additional properties, such as address and phone number. Now here comes the hard part:

> Every user can be multiple types of additional users

To give a little example, here are 2 classes of additional users:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class UserWithCar extends MyBaseUser
{
    private $brand;
    private $color;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class UserWithPonyTail extends MyBaseUser
{
    private $length;
    private $color;
}
```

This data is completely fictional of course, I am not making an application about user with pony tails driving cars...
Now, when mapping these, Doctrine generates 4 tables, which is correct of course. And each table contains the correct, limited, amount of fields:

```
User: id, username, password, discr
MyBaseUser: id, address, phoneNumber
UserWithCar: id, brand, color
UserWithPonyTail: id, length, color
```

If I enter the data, I can get the complete user such as a `UserWithPonyTail` that has all the properties of `MyBaseUser`. If I have the data in `UserWithCar` for the same user, I can fetch that user as a `UserWithCar`. A User can both hava a car and a pony tail.

My problem lies with the fact that each user can only be one type of user at the same time. If a user has the `mybaseuser` discriminator, it can only be used as a `MyBaseUser`. This leads to the problem that when I ask my `UserWithPonyTailRepository` for it's users, it will return the entity of the user to which it is discriminated. If, for example, I have a `UserWithPonyTail` with id `1` and I want to retrieve it using the `UserWithPonyTailRepository` but the `User` with id `1` has the discriminator `mybaseuser` I will receive a `MyBaseUser` which of course does not contain the data of `UserWithPonyTail`.

Is there any way around this or am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Probably completely wrong.  Maybe make a Car and Ponytail entity each with an optional 1:1 relation with the user.  So a user can have both a car and ponytail but it is the same user.

Comment: @Cerad let's say my users aren't `UserWithPonyTail` or `UserWithCar` but rather `Doctor` or `Musician`. The musician and doctor are the same 'entity' as the user, it just expands on it's data. What would I do in that situation?   

A user doesn't have to know it can be a doctor or a musician, it should just know it's a user. The doctor or musician _should_ know they're a user but also have some extra data.  

Should I just make a one-to-one unidirectional mapping from Doctor to user instead of extending that base user? That might be a better idea I think

Comment: Yes.  Drop this base user stuff.  You hardly ever inheritance for this.  Make a Doctor entity and associate it with the user.

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem, to get both type of users using the repo, just ask the "parent" repo to get users Ex:
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyBundle:MyBaseUser")->findAll(). and every "user" will have the correct disc